# Extend generic type in Class Members and methods

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-class

I'm not really sure about this implementation, I can clearly understand the problem but I'm not sure on the right syntax. `private db: Map<string, any>` works but that's not the way to go.

```
class Collection {
  private db: Map<string, GenericItem> = new Map(); // I would like to use 'GenericItem' here, but it is not assignable to 'T'.

  setItemByName<T extends GenericItem>(name: string, item: T): void {
  this.db.set(name, item);
  }

  getCollectionItemByName<T extends GenericItem>(name: string): T {
    // Type 'GenericItem' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    // 'GenericItem' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', 
    // but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'GenericItem'.
    return this.db.get(name);
  }
}

class GenericItem { name = null; }
class Geometry extends GenericItem { faces = 'squares';}
class Human extends GenericItem { age = 12; }

const collection = new Collection();
const cube = new Geometry();

collection.setItemByName<Geometry>('cube', cube);

const cubeItem = collection.getCollectionItemByName<Geometry>('cube');

// narrowing the type with generics let inference instance properties and have an error message
console.log(cubeItem.age); // Property 'age' does not exist on type 'Geometry'.
```

Comment: Just remove generic type `T` and use `GenericItem` instead ? tinyurl.com/2addn2yh

Comment: Can you explain why you need the generic there?  It seems you intend to keep track of exactly which subtype of `GenericItem` gets put into which key, but `Map<string, GenericItem>` does not keep track of that.  In your code, nothing stops the caller from calling `collection.getCollectionItemByName<Human>('cube');`, which is why the implementation of `getCollectoinItemByName` is a problem and why there's an error.   You can use assertion functions like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2KazN) but they are fragile, or builders like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBPk4W) but requires usage changes.

Comment: If you would like me to turn one or more of those code suggestions into an answer, let me know.

Comment: As you both suspected I want to narrow the type. I'll update the example to make clear where the problem could be.

Comment: @Psidom this is why I would like to extend GenericItem tinyurl.com/nrcjj2vx

Comment: Clarification please, you want an assurance that if you do `collection.setItemByName<Geometry>('cube', cube);` then you will get a compilation error when doing this `collection.getCollectionItemByName<Human>('cube');` ? - If so, then I don't think it is possible to know that this is not allowed at compile time.

Comment: Not exactly, the error will be at compilation and at runtime, when two types don't  correspond, for instance when `console.log(cubeItem.age)` when `cubeItem` is  not an instance of `Human`. TS is perfectly capable of narrowing the type to `Geometry` if told so, but when the collection type is just a superclass `GenericType` all checks are lost. Now, my implementation is an anti-pattern, I don't know (that's why I'm asking). I would just have better control over the inheritance and have the most non generic type from my collection. If you have better example I'm all ears!